# DeviceUseTrigger Task has no access to wifi when screen is off WP8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, background-process, background-task

I have a pretty straight forward question. I'm running a deviceusetrigger task on a windows phone 8.1 app. The task runs fine but it cannot access the wifi when the phone screen is off.

What can I do to allow the background task to use wifi with the screen off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wifi is apparently not available with the screen off.

Comment: Is this really the case or did you find any other solution?

Comment: Yes this is really the case. No access to wifi when the screen is turned off. Apparently cell data is available in this case.